# PHP Check if part or the entire word is contained in the string

Tags: php

I have these two strings:

```
blablab/wp-forum.php?link

blablab/wp-forum.php
```

How can I check in PHP if the **second** one is contained in the **first** one or not?

I cannot find a working and easy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs for the function [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)
Or [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
Or [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: `strpos("blablab/wp-forum.php?link", "blablab/wp-forum.php")`

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "blablab/wp-forum.php?link";
$find = "blablab/wp-forum.php";

$position = strpos($str, $find);

if($position !== FALSE)   // !== operator to check the type as well. As, strpos returns 0, if found in first position
{
   echo "String contains searched string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos` to locate the first occurence of such a string

```
      <?php 
      $pos = strpos($largerString,$fimdMe);
      if($pos === false) {
        // string $findMe not found in $largerString
      }
     else {
      // found it 
    }
    ?>
```